# Dispatch Queues - Nesting, Optimisation & Control

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

Can I have your advice on the approved approach?

I have four processes that need to run sequentially:

```
calculateProcess1()
calculateProcess2()
calculateProcess3()
calculateProcess4()
```

These calculate data and update progress bars (circular) and other screen literals using dispatch queues to make the UI update.

Run them as is and lo and behold they all fire off simultaneously (what a surprise!).

How do I make the top level calls run in sequence (as above) and do I need to make changes to my DispatchQueues in the processes for updating the literals, e.g.:

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync { 
     let progressPercentage = (day*100/365)
     self.progressLabel.text = String(Int(progressPercentage))+"%"  
}
```

The initiating processes (calculateProcess1-4()) need to run from main. Should this be in ViewDidLoad, a button action or what is the most secure method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one approach would be to use [`Operation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) and [`OperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue). Setting `maxConcurrentOperationCount: Int` to `1` on the `OperationQueue`, will force operations to be performed in a sequence, one after another.

(Previously called `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`)

This blogpost can be helpful: https://nshipster.com/nsoperation/

And of course awesome WWDC15 session: [Advanced NSOperations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for these steers - I'll go read and implement.

Answer (score 2):

1- Don't `sync` in main thread as it'll cause a runtime crash , it should be `async`

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
```

2-

> Should this be in ViewDidLoad, a button action or what is the most secure method?

it's up to you there is no thing related to security here , implement it as your UX

3- to run them in dequence create a custom Queue then dispatch them in it as it' ll run serially if the code inside all these methods run in the same thread of the queue meaning you don't internally dispatch inside another queue , you can also use `DispatchGroup` to be notified when all are done

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep it simple you can provide callback blocks to your `calculateProcess` methods and simply nest them.

```
calculateProcess1() {
    calculateProcess2() {
        calculateProcess3() {
            calculateProcess4() {}
        }
    }
}
```

> Should this be in ViewDidLoad, a button action or what is the most
>   secure method?

`viewDidLoad` is probably what you want. Keep in mind if you instantiate a new viewController of the same type and show it, it will happen again, once, for that new controller as well. Also, if you are doing anything with view frames, those are not guaranteed to be laid out in `viewDidLoad`, but if you are simply updating text then it should be fine.

Comment: Get "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" when I use your nesting: 
calculateProcess1() {
    calculateProcess2() {
        calculateProcess3() {
            calculateProcess4() {}
        }
    }
}

whereas:

calculateProcess1()
calculateProcess2()
calculateProcess3()
calculateProcess4()

compiles.

Comment: @EdwardHasted You have to add the callback block to the method as an argument. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Comment: That compiles but sticks - let me read those notes fully - many thanks.